# Linear or Nonlinear function?

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-system

I want to know if the below two function are Linear or not. I have been searching in Google but found some confusing results. The first one is an inequality and the second one is just a function and both are function of $w$.

$[1.] -(w-1) \frac{Z g p_{max} + \sigma^2}{g_{pu} p_{pu}} \leq \log q$

$[2.] f(w) = -\alpha' \log_2(w)$

Any explanation will be highly appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is clearly nonlinear. Why? Well, differentiate with respect to $w$: if it were linear, the result would be a multiple of $w$, but this is not the case.

The left-hand side of the first "thing" is linear in $w$ (it is a multiple of $w-1)$), but I am not sure if you are asking this.

Comment: thank u for your answer. :)

Comment: But, linearity of a function $f$ is not proved by differentiating $f$. Linearity is a concept coming from linear algebra. What you would have to do is showing that $f$ preserves vector addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: In this particular question, I believe that using calculus was the best idea. We all know that a logarithm is nonlinear, but OP did not. I could have shown that the logarithm of a sum is not, in general, the sum of the logarithms. But the OP was looking for a very intuitive explanation.

Comment: Well, I would have preferred your proof of linearity, because then you might have realized that the "additions" involved in the proof are two distinct operations, one defined on the domain ($\mathbb{R}_{>0}$) and the other on the image ($\mathbb{R}$) of the logarithm. However "addition" on the domain turns out to be the usual arithmetic product and not the usual arithmetic sum of two positive real numbers, because otherwise there wouldn't be an inverse operation (subtraction is not closed!!!). The confusion happens when the same symbol (+) for the two "additions" is used.

Comment: I guess that all this discussion is really meaningless to the OP. As far as I can understand, his/her level of abstraction is rather low, and the whole issue was probably to decide whether a function is "linear" in the sense that it has the form $ax+b$. He or she knows nothing about groups and abstract vector spaces (otherwise we would have not read such a question at all, I believe), and therefore I used the fact that a function is "linear" (i.e. affine) if and only if $f'$ is constant. This fact is false itself, but in this case all the assumptions can be reasonably taken for granted.

Comment: @Siminore For some strange reason, your commenter is pushing the agenda on several mse pages that one can only add positive numbers, not substract them. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1495887/ Yeah, rather odd... As far as I am concerned, your answer is tuned at what can imagine the level of understanding by the OP is. +1.

Comment: @Siminore For some strange reason, the previous commenter is pushing the agenda that *closure of a binary operation*, such as subtraction, is irrelevant and that we shouldn't care whether 3 apples - 5 apples = -2 apples really exist.

Sure, at school we were mainly dealing with the additive group of real numbers (even if we didn't know). And right, in this case only affine functions are linear.

What I wanted to make aware of is: If we know that we are actually dealing with *positive-real numbers* (see domain of log), then we should take into account that they are multiplicative.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**: none of them are linear.
**Explanation**: A function is linear if:

\begin{equation}
f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y) \\
f(cx)  = cf(x)
\end{equation}

**[1.]**

If it is a function of $\omega $, assuming that the dependent variable is $q$ and the rest are constants, we can reexpress it renaming the constants (just for Calculus simplicity) like:

\begin{equation}
-(w - 1)k_1 \le k_2 \Rightarrow  \log{q(w)} \ge k_1 - w  \Rightarrow q{
(\omega)} \ge e^{k_1-w}
\end{equation}

Which in the equality you can see (you can also picture it graphically since an exponential function won't be a line) that any of the two hold

\begin{equation}
q(w_1+w_2) = e^{k_1-w_1 - w_2} = e^{k_1-w_1}e^{-w_2} \ne e^{k_1-w_1} + e^{k_1-w_2} = q(w_1)+q(w_2)  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
q(cw_1) = e^{k_1-cw_1 } \ne ce^{k_1-w_1} = cq(w_1)  
\end{equation}

**[2.]**

For $-\alpha \log_2{w}$ clearly none of them holds, $\log_2{w_1 + w_2} \ne \log_2{w_1} + \log_2{w_2}$, and $\log{cw} = \log{c} + \log{w}   \ne c\log{w} $

Answer (score 0):

I will only give an answer regarding the second item.

Even if most people will contend that $f(w) = -\alpha' \log_2(w)$ was clearly non-linear, this is not so if you consider the domain and the image of $f$ to be vector spaces. Generally, ...

> ... a function $f : V \to W$ between two vector spaces $(V,\oplus,\odot)$ and $(W,\boxplus,\boxdot)$ over a field $F$ (the set of scalars) is linear, if and only if it preserves the vector addition and the scalar multiplication.

So, you would have to show that
$$
f(a \oplus b) = f(a) \boxplus f(b) \quad \text{and} \quad f(\lambda \odot a) = \lambda \boxdot f(a)
$$
for all $a,b \in V$ and $\lambda \in F$.

> **Claim:** Let $(V,\oplus,\odot)$ and $(W,\boxplus,\boxdot)$ be two vector spaces over a field $F$ where
>
> - $V := \mathbb{R}_{>0}$,
> - $a \oplus b := a \cdot b$,
> - $\lambda \odot a := a^\lambda$,
>
> and
>
> - $W := \mathbb{R}$,
> - $a \boxplus b := a + b$,
> - $\lambda \boxdot a := \lambda \cdot a$.
>
> Then $f : V \to W, \, w \mapsto -\alpha'\log_2(w)$ is linear.

Too see this, check the two conditions of linearity.
$$
f(a \oplus b) = f(a \cdot b) = -\alpha' \log_2(a \cdot b) = -\alpha' \log_2(a) -\alpha' \log_2(b) = f(a) + f(b) = f(a) \boxplus f(b)
$$
and
$$
f(\lambda \odot a) = f(a^\lambda) = -\alpha' \log_2(a^\lambda) = -\alpha' \lambda \log_2(a) = \lambda \cdot f(a) = \lambda \boxdot f(a).
$$
So, $f$ is linear.

Comment: -1. Squarely offtopic (even if this corresponds to the OP's pet-peeve).